# How can I get an upstart script to properly manage running a docker image?

Tags: docker, upstart

I have a local docker-registry that I'd like to manage with [upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/).

I have the following script (in ***/etc/init/docker-registry.conf***):

```
description "docker registry" 
author "me" 
start on filesystem and started docker 
stop on runlevel [!2345] 
respawn 
script
    /usr/bin/docker.io run -a stdout --rm --name=docker-registry \
    -v /var/local/docker-registry:/var/local/docker-registry \
    -p 5000:5000 mysite:5000/docker-registry
end script
```

---

#### I can start my docker registry fine with:

```
sudo start docker-registry
```

Response: *docker-registry start/running, process 8620*

#### Check to confirm its running?

```
sudo status docker-registry
```

Response: *docker-registry start/running, process 8620*

#### Trying to stop it with:

```
sudo stop docker-registry
```

Response: *docker-registry stop/waiting*

**However, it doesn't actually stop.  The process is still alive, the container is running, and it's still functioning perfectly**

---

It does stop perfectly with:

```
docker stop docker-registry
```

I've tried adding this to the upstart script:

```
post-stop script
    docker stop docker-registry
end script
```

But it just returns:
*stop: Job failed while stopping*

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me:

```
description "container foo"
author "me"
start on filesystem and started docker
stop on runlevel [!2345]
respawn
script
  /usr/bin/docker start -a foo
end script
pre-stop script
  /usr/bin/docker stop foo
end script
```

I'm assuming [the official Docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/articles/host_integration/) only care about the automatic starting part. The actual PID output by upstart differs from the actual docker process PID, and I suspect this causes some mismatch when stopping:

```
sudo service foo-docker start
foo-docker start/running, process 30313
```

What is this process? It looks like it's how Docker launched the container:

```
ps -p 30386 -f
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root     30386     1  0 14:48 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh -e -c /usr/bin/docker start -a foo  /bin/sh
```

The PID of the actual command running inside the container is a different one:

```
pidof foo
30400
```

And killing the docker PID, as I guess the `service foo-docker stop` does, does not kill the container (or the command running within it):

```
sudo kill 30386 # or sudo service foo-docker stop
#30400 is still running
```

Answer (score 3):

Try prefixing the `docker run` line with `exec`.  This will cause the docker container to run within the context of the shell script rather then the shell forking it.  As a result, the `docker run` binary will receive the signals and clean itself up.

For example I have the following:

```
description "Docker container for OpenVPN server"
start on filesystem and started docker
stop on runlevel [!2345]
respawn
script
  exec docker run --volumes-from ovpn-data --rm -p 1194:1194/udp --cap-add=NET_ADMIN kylemanna/openvpn
end script
```

And running `start docker-openvpn` and `stop docker-openvpn` works as expected (--rm is honored as well).

Tested on `Docker version 1.4.0, build 4595d4f` on Ubuntu 14.04.

If it doesn't work, consider updating to use the upstream docker apt repo:

```
   curl https://get.docker.io/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
   echo deb http://get.docker.io/ubuntu docker main | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y lxc-docker
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to call docker stop here
Upstart's stop command will send the SIGTERM signal to the container which is the same thing.

There may be an issue with getting --rm to work here, though. There is an open issue on Github about it

Comment: Apparently, it *isn't* the same thing.  I removed the `--rm`, and upstart still fails to stop my container.  `docker stop docker-registry` still works though.

Answer (score 0):

To make your pre-stop script work, just add "rm" to clean up the named container, so:

```
...
...
pre-stop script
  /usr/bin/docker stop [container name]
  /usr/bin/docker rm   [container name]
end script
```

You can also avoid having to start (as in "docker start" vs "docker run") a container in this case as well (start only works if you already did a run and stop). So your start script looks like:

```
...
script
   /usr/bin/docker rm [container name] | true
   /usr/bin/docker run [-v vol:vol] [-p port:port] --name=[container name] [docker tag]
end script
```

For this to work, you'll need to run with --name, or stop can't find your container. If you really want to start -a, you can run, stop, start in your startup script.

Complete example:

```
description "storm supervisor docker container"
author "youremail@emailprovider.domain"

start on filesystem and started docker
stop on runlevel [!2345]
respawn
script
        /usr/bin/docker rm storm-supervisor | true
        /usr/bin/docker run --name="storm-supervisor" -v /var/log/docker-storm-supervisor:/var/log -p 6700:6700 -p 6701:6701  -p 6702:6702 -p 6703:6703 -p 6704:6704 -p 6705:6705 -p 6706:6706 tycoon/storm-supervisor
end script

pre-stop script
        /usr/bin/docker stop storm-supervisor
        /usr/bin/docker rm storm-supervisor
end script
```

Comment: You want to use `||`, not `|`, right? Otherwise you're just piping the output of the Docker command to `true`, when really you want the OR operator to return success from the Docker command or the `true` command.

Answer (score -2):

You can use `--restart=always` when starting docker-registry, i.e.

```
docker run -d --restart=always docker-registry
```

This way the image will automatically restart together with a machine restart, just like upstart.

More information on restart policies [here](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#restart-policies)

Comment: Output from command: flag provided but not defined: --restart

Usage: docker start [OPTIONS] CONTAINER [CONTAINER...]

Comment: --restart is part of docker run not start

Comment: Using two process managers such as `docker built-in restart flag` and `upstart` is not recommended